# Question title not updated after edit is approved

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

After I just approved an edit to a question title, I noticed that it wasn't automatically updated (AJAX). If an edit to the body of a question is approved, however, it gets updated. Was this not thought of or just never implemented?

Comment: yeah it is a bug ... not implemented yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ghetto](http://youtu.be/sd7lanc60rU) fix implemented - the page will refresh when approved.